# Dynamic polymorphic type deduction using decltype

Tags: c++, polymorphism, decltype

Could you please give me a hint, how to make this code to work as I want it to? I want `derived_t` to be `Derived`, but it's always `Base`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

struct Base {
    virtual std::string me() { return "Base"; }
};

struct Derived : Base {
    virtual std::string me() override { return "Derived"; }
};

void foo(std::shared_ptr<Base> ptr) {

    using derived_raw_t = decltype(*ptr);
    using derived_t = std::remove_reference<derived_raw_t>::type;

    derived_t* x = new derived_t();
    std::cout << x->me() << std::endl;
}

int main() {

    std::shared_ptr<Base> ptr = std::make_shared<Base>(Derived());

    foo(ptr);
}
```

Comment: `decltype` deduces static (compile time) type, which is `Base` in this case. You can add a factory virtual function into `Base` class to produce an instance of this class and call it to create `x` invoking factory method of `Derived` and creating a new instance of `Derived` type.

Comment: Why do you need the derived type in `foo`? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You won't be able to do that via `decltype` as that is a compile-time facility. Your best bet is to provide a `virtual` function `create()` in the base overridden in the various derived classes to create an object of the respective type. Typically, a copy is needed and the corresponding function is name `clone()`.

Comment: You can't determine the compile-time type of a variable from the runtime type of an object.

Comment: That a derived class can be pointed to by a base class pointer doesn't make the pointer any less of a base class pointer. Of course dereferencing it will yield a base class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your goal is unclear from your question. Regardless, `decltype(e)` is behaving as expected here as it will return the "declared type of `e`", which is known at compile-time.

It is impossible to retrieve the actual type of a derived class at run-time using `decltype`. If you want to "clone" depending on the run-time type of a polymorphic object, you can use `virtual` and `override`. E.g.:

```
struct Base {
    // ...
    virtual std::shared_ptr<Base> clone() { 
        return std::make_shared<Base>(*this); 
    }
};

struct Derived : Base {
    // ...
    virtual std::shared_ptr<Base> clone() { 
        return std::make_shared<Derived>(*this); 
    }
};
```

If you want to emulate covariance, see: [How To Make a clone method using shared_ptr and inheriting from enable_shared_from_this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655390)

Comment: The goal is to make clone function in the derived class to return pointer to derived, not to base. Can I use another way to know when I have derived instance or base? E.g. typeid().name works somehow, but I need not a const char* of the type, but the type itself

Comment: @banana36: see the link I posted at the end, and improve your question with you real goal.

Comment: Yeah, the link helped. Thanks.